# How can I center an image of an unknown width?

Tags: css

Using CSS how can I center an image of unknown dimensions?

Comment: The correct answer will differ depending on whether the image is content (for scrutiny) or merely decorative (style).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Horizontally

```
img {display:block; margin: 0 auto}
```

or

```
.container {text-align:center}
```

#### Vertically

```
/* container must contain some text as well */
.container, img {line-height:100px; vertical-align:middle}
```

or

```
.container {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
```

#### If image is only decorative:

```
.container {background: url(…) 50%;}
```

Comment: You can see the example just here: http://jsfiddle.net/RHu6Y/ the unique problem, is that you have to specify the width and (or) height of the parent containter

Comment: what about if the image, are two images one above the other in an absolute position?

Answer (score 7):

Seeing as images are native `inline-block` elements (I think - at least not `block`),

```
text-align: center
```

for the surrounding container will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS like this:

```
img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```